# Google analytics regex goal not working correctly

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a regex to track signups to my site. There could be multiple adresses for a goal.

Here is my regex:

`(\/membership\/signed-up\/|\/membership\/campagin\/(?!.*(not-this-campaign)).[-\w]+\/signed-up\/)`

I want to match this adresses:

```
/membership/signed-up/
/membership/campagin/random-campaign/signed-up/
/membership/campagin/other-random-campaign/signed-up/
```

But I want to exclude this address:

`/membership/campagin/not-this-campaign/signed-up/`

It works, but it google also matches this address:

`/membership/signed-up/step-2/`

When I test in http://regexr.com it matches only on the strings I want, but why is google analytics matching more?

Comment: GA does not use JS, but RE2 regex flavor. It does not support lookarounds. Do not rely on http://regexr.com/ much.

Comment: So, it is not possible to exclude something in the regex goal?

Comment: You might express *not starts with* and *not ends with* with this engine, but not *does not contain*. Use exclude filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
(\/MEMBERSHIP\/SIGNED\-UP\/(?!.*(STEP\-2))|\/MEMBERSHIP\/CAMPAGIN\/(?!.*(NOT\-THIS\-CAMPAIGN)).[-\w]+\/SIGNED\-UP\/)
```

You regex its almost correct, but, you need to ensure it dont match with *STEP 2*